# Procedure to deploy webapplication using yeoman, bower and grunt on Lighttpd web server

Tags: gruntjs, lighttpd, bower-install, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm new to the Yeoman,Bower and Grunt, If anyone help me how to configure to deploy the webapplication onto Lighttpd webserver.